# standalone.xml doesn't delete deployment after stop jboss application server wildfly

Tags: deployment, wildfly

I have a project which uses Wildfly to deploy. But when I stop the server, the development tags in standalone.xml aren't deleted. So the next time I run the server, it will catch error.

Here is standalone.xml deployment tags

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="sqljdbc42.jar" runtime-name="sqljdbc42.jar">
        <content sha1="ff439c53190a987d327165dec8b148f670cb7ca8"/>
    </deployment>
    <deployment name="nts.uk.com.js.web.war" runtime-name="nts.uk.com.js.web.war">
        <fs-exploded path="/home/local/3SI/ha.dhv/3SProjects/UniversalK/nts.uk/uk.base/base.web/nts.uk.com.js.web/build/libs/exploded/nts.uk.com.js.web.war"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Comment: Why do you think it should do this?  If you've deployed the application then it should remember that the next time it starts.  If you don't want that, undeploy the application before shutdown.

Comment: I deploy using run/debug configuration in IntelliJ. It should be undeploy when I stop the server. Isn't it the right way to happend?

Comment: That's Intellij responsibility. How could WildFly know that this is not a real deployment ?